# Web Application Error Reporting

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, web-applications

there was a web application, that you could configure so that
over the api, your app could post the error logs into that
application.

it was a paid service and the free version allowed you to do like
1 report a minute.

if any of you remember this service, please post it as an answer.

thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [Hoptoad](https://hoptoadapp.com/). There are libraries/middleware for RoR, [Django](http://stevelosh.com/projects/django-hoptoad/) and [PHP](http://github.com/rich/php-hoptoad-notifier). The free service allows 5 per minute.

Comment: sure :) just let me finish my registration :D

Comment: @Herr Kaleun - if you love the answer maybe you should upvote it. I did since it wasn't.